# [Android]Prevent from hiding keyboard when EditText's focus is released

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

I have a Fragment which contains EditText and Button.

My goal is to achieve the following behavior.

1. When this Fragment is shown, soft-keyboard doesn't appear.
2. When the EditText gets focused, soft-keyboard appears.
3. A user enters words via soft-keyboard.
4. When the Button is clicked, EditText's text is cleared, **keeping the EditText has focus, and keeping the soft-keyboard appears**.
5. When a user taps anywhere except the EditText and the Button, soft-keyboard hides.

However, I Can't realize 4th and 5th step.

When I click the Button, the focus of EditText is automatically released and the soft-keyboard hides as well. (Actually, it happens wherever I tap except the EditText)

I can realize similar behavior by showing keyboard programmatically in the Button's OnClickListener, but this is not what I really want to, because the soft keyboard does appear after once hiding.

Now, how can I realize 4th step ??

Answer (score 0):

**4:** when the button is clicked set the text value to an empty string

```
editText.setText("");
```

this won't affect anything but sets the editText to an empty String, and it keeps the soft-Keyboard shown.

**5:** in your Activity implement `View.OnClickListener` , add `onClick()` method as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.relativelayout_id){
            // hide soft keyboard on touching the background
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

add this line to stop the click sound, you don't need that when you click on the background.

```
relativeLayout.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your advice did not work. Even if I write nothing in Button's OnClickListener, soft-keyboard hides when the button is clicked. Besides, when the background is clicked, the soft-keyboard hides as well even though I don't implement any clickLisner for the view.